# How to merge ONLY unique records from several CSVs with windows batch scripting?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a big help from the community, please if somebody can give me some hints.  I have the following windows batch script which is supposed to read more than 10 million records as different CSV files and merge them all together. I am running the script on the server. So it's not very slow. But the problem is that the code doesn't handle duplicated records. I am not sure how to change the script in order to handle the duplication records and only passed unique records. I would be very very appreciated for your help.

```
rem Set current working directory to Task folder
set FilePath=%~dp0
set FolderPath=%FilePath:~0,-1%


rem Set Space environment variables
call "%FolderPath%"\..\SpaceEnv.bat

rem Set Task specific environment variables
set TaskName=MergeCSVfiles
set fileName=result.csv
set LogFile=%TaskName%_%LogDateTime%.log


:begin
cd ..
cd "Source Files\DCM_Source\Inbox"
echo Staring merge %fileName% at: %time%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "first=1"

>%fileName% (
    for %%F in (msource*.csv) do (
        if not "%%F"=="%fileName%" (
            set /p "header="<"%%F"
            if defined first (
                type "%%F"
                set "first="
            ) else (
                type "%%F" |find /V "!header!"
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal

echo Finish merging %fileName% at: %time%
```

******UPDATED****** 
Example of CSV file

```
Sites|Level 2 sites|Date-time (visit start)|Visit ID|Unique visitor ID|Date-time (event)|Sources|Visitor categories|Visitor ID|Visits
SE Romania|PRM|2018-01-01T00:30:04|1|-6427177464|2018-01-01T00:30:04|Portal sites|-|0|2
SE Romania|PRM|2018-01-01T00:30:04|1|-6427177464|2018-01-01T00:30:04|Portal sites|-|0|2
```

Comment: Are you saying there are duplicate records in each file or duplicates once all the files are merged together?

Comment: Does the final resultfile have to be in any specific order?

Comment: There can be some records by any mistake duplicate in each CSV files, at the end after merging I have them in the merge file as well. @Squashman

Comment: @Magoo   Yes, there I need only one header at the beginning. each CSV files have their header and all the headers are the same.

Comment: Use a different scripting language, batch files are not suited to this type of task unless they also incorporate other languages or tools.

Comment: @Compo I know but I can't change it.

Comment: I agree with @Compo.  I have batch file code I can give you that will dedupe a file but it will probably choke if the file is too big and it will also take forever to run.  A third party utility would be much better.

Comment: @Squashman if it works, it's fine. It's admin script we don't allow to use another thing unfortunately.

Comment: I can't code it to skip your header record.  I will post the code, you will have to figure out how to get your header record back as the top line.

Comment: Ok, thank u , hope i can figure it out ;)

Comment: What is the maximum number of `msource*.csv` files on disk?

Comment: @Aacini it's more than around 1000 CSV files, and each one is very huge.

Answer (score 0):

This code will dedupe a file.  In order to do that it must be sorted.  This means any header record at the top of the file will be sorted into the file. This is code I received from dbenham. I can't remember if he originally posted it on StackOverflow or DosTips.com.  If the file is very large it will more than likely crash with an out of memory error.

```
@echo off
:: Call function to dedupe file
CALL :DEDUPE "filename.txt"
goto :eof

:DEDUPE
:: DEDUPE file
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file=%~1"
set "sorted=%file%.sorted"
set "deduped=%file%.deduped"
::Define a variable containing a linefeed character
set LF=^


::The 2 blank lines above are critical, do not remove
sort "%file%" >"%sorted%"
>"%deduped%" (
  set "prev="
  for /f usebackq^ eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in ("%sorted%") do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if /i "!ln!" neq "!prev!" (
      endlocal
      (echo %%A)
      set "prev=%%A"
    ) else endlocal
  )
)
>nul move /y "%deduped%" "%file%"
del "%sorted%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you, by the way, I hope I can figure it out how would works with mine. I also updated the question with an example.

Comment: You should consider deduping each input file first.  And then running your merge.

Comment: Then in case of having same records in two different CSV file, we wouldn't handle it.  What about if first we merge and then we remove the duplication? Also maybe it's better in terms of performance?

Comment: I've tried the code seems to work fine, but there is one issue, I don't know how to solve, the header is in the end of the file instead of in the first row. Do u know how to modify it?

Comment: with a large file, I am getting the error "not enough main memory to complete the sort."

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filenamecommon=q49264647*.csv"
:: switch to required source directory
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
:: get header line
FOR %%f IN (%filenamecommon%) DO FOR /f "delims=" %%h IN (%%f) DO SET "header=%%h"&goto gotheader
:gotheader
COPY %filenamecommon% atempfilename
SET "lastline="
>resultfilename (
ECHO %header%
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('sort atempfilename' ) DO (
 IF "%%d" neq "!lastline!" IF "%%d" neq "%header%" ECHO %%d
 SET "lastline=%%d"
)
endlocal
)

DEL atempfilename

popd

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used file/dirctorynames that suit my system for testing.

Note : datafiles containing the characters `!` or `^` or unbalanced `"` will not be processed correctly.

First, find the header line by `set`ting `header` from any matching filename. Once `header` is set, forcibly abort the `for` loops.

`copy` and concatenate all of the required files to a tempfile.

output the header line, then sort the tempfile to group identical lines. Read the result and output only those lines that differed from the previous and were not header lines.

Applying `/i` to the `if` statements will make the entire routine disregard character-case.

Sort the tempfile

Comment: Thank you, I am going to test both solutions, I am very appreciated for your reply. I will update you with the new result.